# advantage of object.method(arg) vs method.apply(object, [arg])?

Tags: javascript

Is there an advantage to using `call()` or `apply()` instead of `object.method()`? Can someone provide an example of a situation where one would be preferred over the other? I'm reading through [Chapter 8](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html) of Eloquent JS and it seems like either of the two could be used for the same result.

```
function sayHello(x) {
  console.log("Hello, " + this.first_name + "." + x);
}

var myName = {
  first_name: "John",
  greeting: sayHello
}
```

`myName.greeting(" How are you?");`

vs.

`sayHello.apply(myName, [" How are you?"]);`

Update: Thanks for the info, everyone. I understand `call()` and `apply()`, but I wasn't sure if either were advantageous in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've written it, there is no advantage to using `call()` or `apply()`.  Calling the method directly makes more sense and is easier to read.

`call()` and `apply()` are basically used to explicitly control what object `this` refers to in the context of the function.  Let's say in your example, you didn't want to make `greeting` a property of the `myName` object.  Then you would *have* to use `call()` or `apply()`:

```
function sayHello(x) {
    console.log("Hello, " + this.first_name + "." + x);
}

var myName = {
    first_name: "John",
}

sayHello.call(myName, 'How are you?');
sayHello.apply(myName, ['How are you?']);
```

Or you could use it to call a method on a different object:

```
function sayHello(x) {
    console.log("Hello, " + this.first_name + "." + x);
}

var myName = {
    first_name: "John",
    greeting: sayHello,
}

var herName = {
    first_name: "Mary",
}

sayHello.call(herName, 'How are you?');
sayHello.apply(herName, ['How are you?']);

// you could even get weird...
myName.greeting.call(herName, 'How are you?');
myName.greeting.apply(herName, ['How are you?']);
```

As far as the difference between `call()` and `apply()`, it's just how the arguments are handled.  If you know the arguments beforehand, you can just use `call()` and pass them in as arguments.  If your arguments are variable, you can collect them in an array and use `apply()`.  The canonical example of this is finding the max of an array of numbers:

```
var nums = [ 3, 17, 5, -10, 16 ];
Math.max.apply(null, nums);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It helped a lot. Thanks! I couldn't tell if there was any reason to choose `call()` or `apply()` as opposed to referencing the method directly.

Comment: Glad I could help, Jeff!  It can be confusing...JavaScript offers a lot of flexibility, but it can be weird....

Answer (score 1):

`call` and `apply` as said in other answers  allow you to define `this` for the related function.

jQuery is a great example of this usage as you can access a DOM element in a callback , it allows `$(this)`

Also `apply` is very powerful because it is a great tool when it comes to calling a function with a variable number of known arguments.

More generally `call` and `apply` are often used for [method borrowing](http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/objectoriented-borrowconstructor-example.htm) and a popular example is to use `SomeConstructor.call(this)` within a function to partially apply inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Using call and apply lets you specify the context of the function where invoking it directly the context will be the current scope of "this".

Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).