# How to re-write _.every/_.all from Underscore.js using _.reduce (and _.each)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm working on re-writing the underlying code for many of the standard Underscore.js functions to work on my JavaScript skills and am a bit stuck with the `_.every`/`_.all`.  It appears that in the library itself, the `_.every`/`_.all` function is written only using the existing `_.each` function, but I am being encouraged to write a version using my version of `_.reduce` (which already incorporates my version of `_.each`).  I've provided the code for both functions below.

The first test my `_.every` function (see below as well) fails is one where all false values are passed in using the `_.identity` function (simply return value entered as argument) as the iterator:

Test:

```
  it('fails for a collection of all-falsy results', function() {
    expect(_.every([null, 0, undefined], _.identity)).to.equal(false);
  });
```

I have a few questions as to why my `_.every` function is failing the test shown above, along with multiple other tests (e.g.; mixed true/false values, undefined values, etc.):

-When calling the iterator function, do I need to use `iterator.call` or `iterator.apply`?  If so, which do I use and how do I specify arguments?

-What benefit is there to using `_.reduce` here rather than just `_.each`, especially when the Underscore.js library does not use `_.reduce`?

-Why does return need to be called twice, once when calling the `_.reduce` function, and once within the anonymous function defined within `_.reduce` (I've also wondered this when building functions that utilize the `_.map` function)? To me, it seems like I am returning the result of the `_.reduce` function, which already is returning something.

_.every:

```
  _.every = function(collection, iterator) {
    // TIP: Try re-using reduce() here.
    return _.reduce(collection, function(allFound, item) {
      return iterator(item) && allFound;
    }, true);
  };
```

_.each:

```
_.each = function(collection, iterator) {
  // define spec for arrays
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
    }
  }

  // define spec for objects
  else {
    for(var key in collection) {
      iterator(collection[key], key, collection);
    }
  }
};
```

_.reduce:

```
  _.reduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {

    // add condition to set accumulator if no explicit starting value is given.
    if (arguments.length < 3) {
      accumulator = collection[0];
    }

    _.each(collection, function(value) {
      accumulator = iterator(accumulator, value);
    });

    return accumulator;
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test isn't passing because it's not returning `false` as expected (though it is returning a falsey value).

```
_.every = function(collection, iterator) {
    return _.reduce(collection, function(allFound, item) {
        return iterator(item) && allFound;
    }, true);
};
```

What happens when you return `iterator(item) && allFound` is that if `iterator(item)` is falsey (but not `false`), it will not return `false`, but the value of `iterator(item)`.  To verify this for yourself, open a REPL, and type `undefined && true`; the result will be `undefined`, not `false`.

So if you want this to explicitly return `false`, and not just a falsey value, you'll have to coerce it to a boolean.  You can do either `Boolean(truthy_or_falsey_value)` or `!!truthy_or_falsey_value`.  I usually prefer the latter, so change your implementation thusly:

```
_.every = function(collection, iterator) {
    return _.reduce(collection, function(allFound, item) {
        return !!iterator(item) && allFound;
    }, true);
};
```

Your other questions:

> When calling the iterator function, do I need to use iterator.call or
>   iterator.apply? If so, which do I use and how do I specify arguments?

It depends on what your goal is.  `call` and `apply` are primarily used when you want to control the value of the `this` keyword in the function body.  Some of JavaScript's built-in array methods (like `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.filter`) take a `thisArg`, which is what is supplied do the callback using `call` or `apply`.  As far as the difference between `call` and `apply`, it's only how the arguments are handled.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210768/advantage-of-object-methodarg-vs-method-applyobject-arg/24210917#24210917) for more details.

> What benefit is there to using `reduce` here rather than just `each`,
>   especially when the Underscore.js library does not use `reduce`?

Probably none, or very little.  There could be a performance difference, but the best way to find out would be to profile both approaches.

> Why does return need to be called twice, once when calling the
>   _.reduce function, and once within the anonymous function defined within _.reduce

If you want a function -- any function -- to return a value, you must call return from within that function.  You can't expect to call `return` from an inner function, and expect the enclosing function to magically understand that it's supposed to, in turn, return the value of the called function.  Some languages default to returning the value of the last expression in the function if `return` isn't explicitly called, which is either convenient or confusing, depending on your perspective.  If you have experience with such a language (Ruby, for example), then all the `return` statements may seem a little excessive to you.

As an editorial note, I feel that `iterator` is a poor naming choice for the testing function.  It is not actually iterating over anything (the function that it's an argument to is doing any iteration).  A better name might be the very generic `callback` or `cb`.  The term ["predicate"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29) means a function that maps a value to `true` or `false`, which is my preferred terminology.  Another common choice is simply `test`, since it is, after all, just a function that's performing a binary filter on its argument.